# How do I derive specific data from a string using the Java standard API?

Tags: java

Suppose

```
str = ABCorp(sap234) #$% rain-drop(docman8) 093 (jac3k(turtle))
```

Now how do i derive th followin from the above string:

```
String[] one = {"ABCorp", "rain-drop", "jac3k"}; 
String[] two = {"sap234","docman8","turtle"};
```

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: To answer question 'how': you usually define strict format for your input. E.g., is there any special meaning in _"#$%"_ or additional pair of brackets in the end?

Comment: no nothing special, its jus the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "ABCorp(sap234) #$% rain-drop(docman8) 093 (jac3k(turtle))";

        ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        String s = "\\b(\\p{Graph}+)\\(([^)]+)\\)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("("+s+")|(\\("+s+"\\))");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        while (m.find()) {
            arr1.add(m.group(m.group(1) == null ? 5 : 2));
            arr2.add(m.group(m.group(1) == null ? 6 : 3));
        }

        String[] one = arr1.toArray(new String[0]);
        String[] two = arr2.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(two));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
[ABCorp, rain-drop, jac3k]
[sap234, docman8, turtle]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. may i know y the specific numbers in the ternary operator?

Comment: You should read up on regular expressions and specifically, groups.

Answer (score 2):

I assume `str = ABCorp(sap234) #$% rain-drop(docman8) 093 (jac3k(turtle))` is whole String,
Use [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Answer (score 1):

By tapping into the awesome power of [Regular Expressions!](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)